# Why does neighbouring group participation increase the rate of reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity

I don't see any reason why the transition state of an S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction that happens after an internal nucleophilic group attacks(which is known as NGP) would be more stable. In fact, the nucleophilic group that attacks is often a strong nucleophile that is quite reactive (more than the leaving group which is usually a weak base) which would only destabilise the transition state when the external nucleophile does attack.

My question is: Why is the internal attack and the external attack combined faster than simply the external attack since the rate of such reactions where neighboring groups are involved is greater than normal S<sub>N</sub>2 reactions?

Comment: I suppose these neighboring groups switch on abilities like dipole in the bond and make way for easier substitution.

Comment: Think entropy, the neighboring group is in the same molecule and held in close proximity.

Comment: Possible somewhat answered here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/65872/21296

Comment: @NotBaran No, that does not answer my question at all. I understand the reason NGP occurs, I just don't understand why it increases the overall rate of the reaction

Comment: This is a bit of a tautology, as you would only hear about NGP if it increased the rate of the reaction. If there was a NGP pathway available that *didn't* increase the rate of the reaction, it would simply not be mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

In neighbouring group participation (NGP), an internal nucleophile first displaces a leaving group in an *intra*molecular sense, forming a ring (usually 3 or 5 membered) which is then opened by the incoming nucleophile *inter*molecularly.

> [image: General NGP Mechanism]
>
> General mechanism of neighbouring group participation (taken from March, *Advanced Organic Chemistry*, **2007**

In the scheme above, Z first displaces X to form a 3 membered ring, which is then opened by Y. Your question then becomes **why is Z faster than Y at substituting X?**

**Collision**

In order for the substitution to take place, the nucleophile must come into alignment with the leaving group. In a general sense, *intra*molecular reactions are usually faster than *inter*molecular since the two reacting groups are tethered together – there is no requirement that they collide in order to react. This is especially evident for *intra*molecular formation of 3 and 5 reasons, since those ring sizes are especially favourable. (Note that *intra*molecular reactions isn't always favourable, for example in macrocyclisations of large rings, where high dilution is needed to close the ring rather than getting *inter*molecular reactivity).

**Entropy**

The reaction between the substrate and the external nucleophile Y in an *inter*molecular fashion is accompanied by a decrease in entropy (two molecules are becoming one in the transition state). Whilst this also happens in the *intra*molecular sense (the molecule is becoming more rigid), it is significantly less than in the bimolecular case.

Its also worth pointing out that its not always 100% clear whether a molecule is reacting via an NGP type pathway, and indeed there are many cases where its been shown that both are operating at the same time, with the intra being faster than the inter, but not sufficiently rapid to prevent any direct *inter*molecular reaction.

Comment: My question was: why is the internal attack+the external attack combined faster than simply the external attack since the rate of such reactions where neighboring groups are involved is greater than normal Sn2 reactions

Comment: You may wish to edit your post - that comment is a lot clearer than your original question