# What is the effect of an electronegative atom being close to (but not directly bonded to) a carbocation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

Does oxygen in 1-methoxy-2-methylpropan-2-ylium affects the tertiary carbocation? Is it destabilized due to its electronegativity?

[image: 1-methoxy-2-methylpropan-2-ylium]

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/65872/9961

Answer (score -4):

since the oxygen in the compound is bounded to alpha carbon atom it will provide -I effect to the carbocation and destabilize it. As it is not directly bonded to the carbocation there will be no resonance effect. Had it been so, it would have stabilized it.
The electronegative atom can create dipole-dipole interactions with the nearby carbocation. These interactions can stabilize the carbocation by aligning the partial positive charge on the carbocation with the partial negative charge on the electronegative atom. This effect is more significant when the electronegative atom is close but not directly bonded to the carbocation.
If the electronegative atom or electron withdrawing functional group is of large size then it may cause steric hindrance (not sure about this one since its not directly bonded).